# Php wordpress filter not working

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, extensibility

In my main plugin, I have a function called get_pages(). This function contains an array for each admin page for the plugin, here is the function:

```
static function get_pages( $page_slug = '' ) {

    $pages = array();
    // Default page properties
    $default_args = array(
        'menu-title' => '',
        'tab-title' => '',
        'parent' => 'admin.php',
        'in-menu' => false,
        'has-tab' => true,
        'tab-side' => false,
        'top-level' => false,
    );

    $pages['sat-options-general'] = array_merge(
        $default_args,
        array(
            'slug' => 'sat-options-general',
            'menu-title' => _x( 'Admin Theme', 'Page title in the menu', 'skizzar_admin_theme' ),
            'tab-title' => _x( 'Admin Theme Options', 'Option tab title', 'skizzar_admin_theme' ),
            'title' => _x( 'Admin Theme Options', 'Option page title', 'skizzar_admin_theme' ),
            'callback' => array( __CLASS__, 'display_general_options_page' ),
            'in-menu' => true,
            'top-level' => true,
        )
    );

    $pages['sat-addons'] = array_merge(
        $default_args,
        array(
            'slug' => 'sat-addons',
            'menu-title' => _x( 'Addons', 'Page title in the menu', 'skizzar_admin_theme' ),
            'tab-title' => _x( 'Addons', 'Option tab title', 'skizzar_admin_theme' ),
            'title' => _x( 'Browse Addons', 'Option page title', 'skizzar_admin_theme' ),
            'callback' => array( __CLASS__, 'display_addons_page' ),
            'in-menu' => true,
        )
    );

    if ( $page_slug ) {
        if ( ! isset( $pages[ $page_slug ] ) ) {
            return null;
        }
        return $pages[ $page_slug ];
    }

    return apply_filters( 'skizzar_admin_theme_tab', $pages, $default_args, $page_slug ); 

}
```

This function gives information for a page called `sat-options-general` and `sat-addons`.

I have added a filter at the bottom of the function so that I can extend this plugin by creating an addon plugin.

In my addon plugin I have the following functions:

```
function add_google_analytics_tab( $pages, $default_args, $page_slug ) {

    // Return
    if ( $page_slug ) {
        if ( ! isset( $pages[ $page_slug ] ) ) {
            return null;
        }
        return $pages[ $page_slug ];
    }

    $pages['sat-ga'] = array_merge(
            $default_args,
            array(
                'slug' => 'sat-ga',
                'menu-title' => 'GA',
                'tab-title' => 'GA',
                'title' => 'GA',
                'callback' => 'display_ga_page',
                'in-menu' => true,
            )
        );
        return $pages;
}
function display_ga_page() {
    //$page_info = self::get_pages( 'sat-addons' );
    //include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'inc/page-addons.php' );
    echo 'GA Settings Go Here';
}
```

The first being the $pages set up that hooks into the custom filter I made as follows:

```
function init() {

...

    add_filter( 'skizzar_admin_theme_tab', array(&$this, 'add_google_analytics_tab', 1, 3) );

...

}
```

The second function is the call back, which should just echo out "GA Settings go here" on the newly created page.

However, the result is that my plugin menu completely dissapears and I get the following errors in the debug.log file:

```
[18-Mar-2016 15:59:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/skizzar-local/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 235
[18-Mar-2016 15:59:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/skizzar-local/wp-content/plugins/skizzar-admin-theme-master/class-sat-menu.php on line 13
```

I can't figure out at all what is going on here and really want to find a solution - I'm sure what I'm trying to do isn't tat hard, but a lot of the main plugin draws on info from the $pages array, so it's important that I am able to inject this code into my plugin.

Comment: You should have `add_filter` directly underneath the specified function, and when you want to call the function you should use `apply_filters`

Comment: Thing is, my functions are wrapped in a Class, so having add_filter just outside my function returns an error - the add_filter needs to be wrapped in it's own function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo in `add_filter` call, you didn't close a bracket after `add_google_analytics_tab`:

```
function init() {

...

    add_filter( 'skizzar_admin_theme_tab', array(&$this, 'add_google_analytics_tab'), 1, 3 );

...

}
```

Comment: Well spotted. can't believe its taken the whole day to figure that out!!! Thanks mate